# Check the render method of `ConnectedField`

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am getting this error message when i used a redux-form into my simple three input fields form.

```
form.jsx

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Signup extends Component {

signupView = () => {
  return (
    <section id="user_login">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSignup}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div className="custom_group">
            <Field type="text" className="trans login_input" title="Username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className="sbt_btn">
          <button className="trans white_bg">SIGN UP</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </form>
    </section>
  )
}
render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.signupView()}</div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isRegistered: state.signup.isRegistered,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  SingupAction: (signupInput) => { dispatch(SingupAction(signupInput)) },
})

const formWrapped = reduxForm({
  form: 'Signup'
})(Signup);
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(formWrapped);
```

P.S The `SingupAction` and `handleSignup` is already working so i have not include them in the code.
And has already defined a `Provider store` in `index.js` file.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified the required `component` property of your `Field`, it should be:

```
<Field 
   type="text" 
   className="trans login_input" 
   title="Username" 
   name="username" 
   placeholder="Username" 
   component="input"  
/>
```

Check [here](https://redux-form.com/8.2.0/docs/api/field.md/#-code-component-component-lt-fieldprops-gt-string-code-required-) for docs

Answer (score 0):

I think you are incorrectly connecting your component to `redux`, try this, [Ref](https://redux-form.com/6.6.2/docs/faq/howtoconnect.md/)

```
Signup = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Signup);

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'Signup'
})(Signup);
```

Comment: @GrayCarry I don't see any import for `SingupAction`. Also check if you have exported the same.